# Convert byte array to BigInteger

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

My numbers are base 256 from left to right and represented in byte array. I would like to convert them to BigInteger such that below examples will work:

- [5] -> 5
- [200] -> 200
- [0,1] -> 256
- [100,2] -> 612

I came up with this solution:

```
    byte[] input = new byte[]{(byte) 200,2};
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(256);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        a = a.add(BigInteger.valueOf(input[i] & 0xFF).multiply(base.pow(i)));
    }
    System.out.println(a);
```

While it works, it feels very inefficient. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoeC I want to find a more efficient way of doing this. Creating multiple BigIntegers is not the best you can do....

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I got a different byte order, my examples will not convert that way

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman But you could just reverse the byte order in the array and *then* use `new BigInteger(array)`. That'd be much most efficient than what you're currently doing.

Comment: @Andreas it sounds more efficient then my solution, but it didn't worked for me. Can you make my examples work with that idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way to create a `BigInteger` from a byte array is to use the [`new BigInteger​(byte[] val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-) constructor:

> Translates a byte array containing the **two's-complement** binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in ***big-endian* byte-order**: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

Since your input array is in *little-endian* order, and you don't want negative numbers returned, you need to reverse the bytes and ensure the first byte is 0-127, so the sign bit is not set. Easiest way to do that is to make the first byte `0`.

Example: `[2, 20, 200]` -> `[0, 200, 20, 2]`

Here is the code for that:

```
private static BigInteger toBigInt(byte[] arr) {
    byte[] rev = new byte[arr.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length; j > 0; i++, j--)
        rev[j] = arr[i];
    return new BigInteger(rev);
}
```

*Test*

```
byte[][] data = { {5},
                  {(byte)200},
                  {0,1},
                  {100,2} };
for (byte[] arr : data)
    System.out.println(toBigInt(arr));
```

*Output*

```
5
200
256
612
```

Answer (score 2):

i know you can do this :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // A negative value
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 }; // -65536
        // A positive value
        bytes = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x00, 0x00 }; // 65536
        BitSet set = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
        set.flip(0, set.length());
        byte[] flipped = set.toByteArray();

        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(flipped);
    }
}
```

I use BitSet for swat bit cause you want left to rigth but BigInteger constructor use rigth to left

Comment: Byte order is reversed from what's in the question.

Comment: sorry i dont see , i have fix that